# How to fix not logged in error while testing?

Tags: java, spring, api, testing, rest-assured

I'm writing a few tests for my API. The API only answers when the user is logged in. I've written a test for the login API and this works, however after i run this test the other tests does not work because the user is not logged on.

Code for testing the login(works):

```
public class FunctionalTest {

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    String port = System.getProperty("server.port");
    if (port == null) {
        RestAssured.port = Integer.valueOf(8080);
    }
    else{
        RestAssured.port = Integer.valueOf(port);
    }


    String basePath = System.getProperty("server.base");
    if(basePath==null){
        basePath = "/";
    }
    RestAssured.basePath = basePath;

    String baseHost = System.getProperty("server.host");
    if(baseHost==null){
        baseHost = "http://localhost";
    }
    RestAssured.baseURI = baseHost;
}
}

public class RestEndpointTests extends FunctionalTest{

//User control <---- WORKS
@Test
public void checkLogin(){
    given()
            .param("email", "123")
            .param("username", "123")
            .param("password", "123")
            .post("/login")
            .then()
            .statusCode(200);
}


//Playlists   <---- DOES NOT WORK
@Test
public void checkPlaylistById() {
    given().when().get("/playlists/1").then()
            .body("name",equalTo("Playlist 1"));
}
```

How to solve this and code the user to be logged in when the checkPlaylistByID is executed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why can't you simply do a login? How does the server identify a logged in user?

Comment: When the user is logged in I'm getting an Xauth token.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a user for the test. How you do it depends on how your security layer works. Here is how I would do for Spring MVC with Spring Security:

```
@Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(USER_LOGIN, USER_PASSWORD);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    restApiNameMockMvc.perform(fileUpload("/api/api_name/stuff")
        .param("param", PARAM_VALUE)
    )
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.testedProperty").value(expectedValue));
}
```

Note that I don't call the login endpoint, I set the context as if a user was already logged in. `MockMvc` doesn't apply Spring Security rules and SecurityContextHolder will hold the user so the tested method can get him.

The method that you test can get that user by using:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()
```

If you didn't make such call, you could just rely on MockMvc and not set a logged in user at all.

Here I'm explicitly setting the logged in user for each test but taking advantage of your testing framework will spare you from having to do so.

Comment: ApiAuthenticationToken is not recognized, is this an import?

Comment: My bad, it's a custom class, a layer over UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. I've edited my answer to use this last class.